# ¿Cómo puedo arreglar estos errores en GoLang?

Tags: visual-studio, go

En el programa me piden que entregue un Cuadrado Latino de orden N.

Un cuadrado latino de orden N es una matriz cuadrada en la que su primera fila contiene N primeros números naturales y cada una de sus N-1 filas contiene la rotación de la fila anterior un lugar a la derecha.

Ejemplo cuadrado latino de orden 4:

> 1 2 3 4
>
> 4 1 2 3
>
> 3 4 1 2
>
> 2 3 4 1

El programa que tengo me esta dando errores que no entiendo muy bien por que aparecen.

Este es mi código:

```golang
package main;

import(
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "bufio"
)

func cuadradoLatino(){
    var i int;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++){
    var temp int = k;
    while (temp <= n) {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", temp);
        temp++;
    }
    var j int;
    for (j=1; j<k; j++)
    fmt.Printf("%d ", j);
    k--;
    fmt.Printf("\n");
}}

func main (){
    capt := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Inserte el valor del cuadro: ")
    capt.Scan()
    n := capt.Text()
    fmt.Print("El cuadrado es: ")
    cuadradoLatino(n);
}
```

Y los errores que me aparecen son los siguientes:

> ```
> .\Cuadrado.go:11:10: syntax error: unexpected semicolon, expecting )        
> .\Cuadrado.go:12:2: syntax error: unexpected {, expecting for loop condition
> .\Cuadrado.go:14:16: syntax error: unexpected - at end of statement
> .\Cuadrado.go:22:9: syntax error: unexpected =, expecting )
> .\Cuadrado.go:27:2: syntax error: unexpected }, expecting expression        
> .\Cuadrado.go:28:1: syntax error: unexpected }, expecting { after for clause
> .\Cuadrado.go:30:6: syntax error: unexpected main, expecting (
> ```

Comment: Te sugiero que sigas los tutoriales oficiales de Go. [Aquí](https://go.dev/tour/flowcontrol/1), en la nota al pie, dice (énfasis mío): _A diferencia de otros lenguajes como C, Java o JavaScript, **no hay paréntesis alrededor de los tres componentes de la sentencia `for` y las llaves { } son siempre necesarias**_. No programes a ciegas, son errores de sintaxis...

Comment: Tal como recomienda @padaleiana has el tour de go (Es documentacion oficial, interactiva y muy fácil de seguir) https://go.dev/tour/flowcontrol/1